# Advisory record lock using python fcntl module?

Tags: python

I am using python fcntl module to apply record lock on a file. when I execute the command using a script from ubuntu (VM), its working fine but when run the script from rhel its not working as expected.

Below is my code:

```
file = open(FILE, "a")

lockData = struct.pack('hhhh', fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0)
```

while True:

```
 try:
      fcntl.fcntl(file, lockCmd, lockData)
      for i in range(50):
          file.seek(0)
          file.write(sys.argv[3]+" : "+str(i)+"\n")
          time.sleep(0.1)

      file.close() # unlocks the file
      break
 except IOError, err:
      print "Error : %s" % err
```

My expectation is when run two instances of this script, then first one will take lock and other one will throws error till close() is not called from first instance. This behavior is  achieved in ubuntu but not in rhel.

Can anyone help??

Comment: It seems some issue with python version. Its working on Ubuntu which have version 2.7.3 but not working on RHEL having version 2.6.6. Now I'm trying with same version or different version on RHEL.